# Работа WPF с ADO.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

Пишу на .Net Framework 4.0, с wpf почти не связывался, работал только с WindowForms. У меня уже есть приложение с использованием ADO.NET, но мне в целях изучения надо попробовать написать это на WPF. Что посоветуете? Есть какие-нибудь уроки или статьи по правильному использованию ADO.NET в WPF ?

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что тут должна быть существенная разница. И в случае WinForms и в случае WPF у вас по-хорошему должен быть слой бизнес-логики, который не должен ничего знать о представлении. А потому работа с данными не будет отличаться в обоих случаях

Comment: Да я так и делал у меня был класс где были все запросы в хранимые процедуры, и возвращали мне DataTable или ArrayList которые я присваивал к DataGrid или полям. Но как это делать в WPF ? Там же есть какие то привязки и т.п. И еще я не знаю как делать подобие SQLDepedency (но это пока не сильно важно)

Comment: DataTable - это DataTable. То есть класс, предназначенный для работы с данными из БД. Сомневаюсь, что это хорошая идея - вводить его содержимое напрямую. У вас должна быть некая модель, которая может заполняться из этого DataTable. А отображение этой модели в WPF (опосредованно через модель представления согласно принципу MVVM) или в WinForms - это уже совершенно иная задача, никак не соотносящаяся со способом получения данных, будь то ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Linq2SQL или что-то еще

Comment: Хорошо я понял. Я так тоже делал, делал класс Модели определённой таблицы, и заполнял её данными из слоя Данных. В форму уже передавал заполненную модель. Это понятно. То есть мне делать аналогично ?

Comment: вам нужно разграничивать собственно модель, работающую с данными, и классы, предназначенные для реализации взаимодействий с интерфейсом. Благодаря этому при работе с данными не будет никакой разницы в том, что использовать - WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET или что-то еще

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятен вопрос автора, так как ADO .NET это набор классов, предоставляющих службы доступа к данным, а WPF это система для построения клиентских приложений Windows с визуально привлекательными возможностями взаимодействия с пользователем.
Могу посоветовать отдельно по WPF книгу на русском

[WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4.0 с примерами на C# 2010 для профессионалов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5914178/)

и очень неплохой ресурс

[WPF - Windows Presentation Foundation](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level1/info_WPF.php)